# How to use jquery in node js?

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am trying to use jquery in my node js file. I installed the jquery module already.

When I visit the page, I get the error:

```
    var jqxhr = jquery.$.getJSON( "favs.json", function() {
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getJSON' of undefined
    at Server.<anonymous>
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2076:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:120:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1966:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:525:27)
```

code:

```
var http = require('http');
var jquery = require('jquery');

var PORT = 3000;

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"});

    var jqxhr = jquery.$.getJSON( "favs.json", function() {
        console.log( "success" );
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log( "second success" );
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log( "complete" );
    });
}).listen(PORT);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + PORT + '/');
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** For recent versions (>=2.1.0), instantiation is done differently and now also requires [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom):

```
var env = require('jsdom').env;
var html = '<html>...</html>';

env(html, function(err, window) {
  console.log(err);

  var $ = require('jquery')(window);
});
```

---

You are not instantiating the jQuery object correctly. This is how it should be done:

```
var jquery = require('jquery');
var $ = jquery.create();
```

Then you can use the method you want to you:

```
$.getJSON('/resource.json', function() {
  console.log('success');
})
  .done(function() {
    console.log('second success');
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log('error');
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log('complete');
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `TypeError: jquery.create is not a function`

Comment: The original answer was posted in 2013 and does not apply to recent versions. I've added an updated example.

Comment: Cool thanks. I already moved on to request/cheerio for my purposes, but thanks for the quick response/fix. :)

Comment: updated one doesn't work. `TypeError: env is not a function`